# Arithmetic operations with expr and variables

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic, floating-point

Why won't this statement work?

```
total=`expr $mPercent / 100 "*" .482 + $fPercent / 100 "*" .518`
```

mPercent is a number as a result of an awk statement, as well as fPercent. I also get "expr: non-numeric argument" as an error message.

**NOTE:** For the purposes of his question, let's say that the 2 variables have the value 3.27.

Comment: This is irrelevant to your issue, but you should not be using backticks, they're deprecated. Use `$()` instead, like so: `total=$(expr ...)`

Comment: For that matter, `expr` itself is obsolete for arithmetic; use `$(( ... ))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` cannot do floating point operations, only integers. I suggest to use `bc -l` instead:

```
$ mPercent='2.72'
$ fPercent='3.14'
$ bc -l <<< $(echo "$mPercent / 100 "*" .482 + $fPercent / 100 "*" .518")
.02937560000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

The `expr` command can only do integer or string manipulations. Look at the man page for this guidance:

> Operands are either integers or strings.  Integers consist of one or
>   more decimal digits, with an optional leading '-'.  'expr' converts
>   anything appearing in an operand position to an integer or a string
>   depending on the operation being applied to it.

So to perform this type of operation you'll need to enlist a command line caluclator such as `bc`.

#### Example

```
$ mPercent='.123'
$ fPercent='.345'
$ echo "$mPercent / 100 * .482 + $fPercent / 100 * .518" | bc -l
.00237996000000000000
```

**NOTE:** `expr` is not part of Bash, it's a standalone executable that's part of the package coreutils. On systems using RPMs you can see this like so:

```
$ rpm -qf $(type -p /usr/bin/expr)
coreutils-8.21-13.fc19.x86_64
```

Using your data that you provided in the comments of 3.27 for the 2 variables yields the following:

```
$ mPercent='3.27'
$ fPercent='3.27'
$ echo "$mPercent / 100 * .482 + $fPercent / 100 * .518" | bc -l
.03270000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that use `bc` for arithmetic operation and `<<<` [(Here String)](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) for inputting the values to `bc`.

```
$ mPercent=3.27
$ fPercent=3.27

$ bc -l <<< "$mPercent / 100 * .482 + $fPercent / 100 * .518"
.03270000000000000000
```

Here `-l` option to `bc` will allow you to use floating point arithmetic with more mathematical functions.

Comment: +1, I have used unnecessary `echo`.